# Going to Amsterdam via the UK when previously denied entry to UK

Tags: air-travel, transit, uk, denial-of-entry

I was stopped twice on 2 different occasions coming into the UK back in 2011 and again in 2012.

The first time I was coming from Spain; I was randomly picked out of the line. They checked my Facebook profile and saw flyers advertising a party in London with my name on the flyer and a £15 cover charge. They claimed I made money without a work visa. I told them I made no money: it was for a benefit for cancer research. They checked back as far as 2006 on FB and saw "more" flyers with my name on it as a DJ and said it seems like you have been doing this for a while based on what we saw on FB. I got sent back to Spain.

The second time was similar, coming in from Spain, my connecting return flight was through the UK but on the next day, I would have to stay one day in London. Same thing: they sent me back to Spain because they thought I was coming into the UK to work (as a Disc Jockey).

I am going to Amsterdam this October. I have to make a connecting flight thru the UK. Will I get stopped while connecting from London to Amsterdam and when I go back to New York City?

Comment: Is your connection airside at the same airport, or do you need to clear immigration?

Comment: there are many direct flights between Spain and the Netherlands, no need to go through the UK. Unless of course your ongoing flight to Amsterdam is a ruse to get through UK customs and stays there...

Comment: I also completely agree with @jwenting. As of now, your intentions seem slightly unclear. Plus you can transit through any other airport in the EU as well. I don't see a reason why you would want to get yourself into trouble by going thru the UK.

Comment: What's your nationality?

Comment: That is quite weird if they went down to your FB page. Either you came across a very strict border agent or you were very very unconvincing in your answers, appearance etc. Your 2 cases seem quite plausible for being refused if you cannot prove otherwise. 2 refusals will surely make the border agent very suspicious, whichever country(non EU) you might be from.

Comment: i am "african american" to answer to question, on this trip i am going to amsterdam(oct 15th to the 20th)i am leaving from jfk then a connecting flight from (philly) strait to amsterdam, on my return ticket has me (amsterdam to uk) connecting at heathrow to american airlines to jfk,that is the way the(ticket) is set up because its a (airline)pass thru a friend at american airlines,the cost for the ticket is very cheap, and that is the only route they have available for this flight, will i be stopped if i can prove I'm just connecting in uk not staying. Romain

Comment: and yes i do have to go thru border control to get to my connecting flight. Romain Gowe

Comment: @RomainGowe nitpicky, but "African American" isn't a nationality. American is.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming it's all one airport (eg NYC-LHR-AMS or similar), if you are allowed onto the flight in New York, you'll be fine

As long as it's all within one airport (so no Stansted-Gatwick changes or similar), and all your bags are checked through (so no need to clear customs + immigration to get bags to re-check), you won't see UK immigration on a transit.

That isn't to say there are no checks!

The UK, in common with many countries, requires visas from many countries even for a direct airside transit in the UK. See [gov.uk for more details](https://www.gov.uk/browse/visas-immigration/transit-visas). As part of that, airlines have to check eligibility for transit without visa, and have to forward passenger details to the UK in advance, so the UK can deny boarding for people not allowed to enter.

If you have to enter the UK to change airports or re-check bags, you'll have to pass UK immigration, who'll see your previous issues and most likely deny you. They'll then most likely put you back on a plane to the USA, maybe even at your expense. From your perspective, this would be bad! If you can do it all airside, it depends on "how naughty you were". Moderately naughty and you shouldn't be on a black list, so should be fine to transit and depart.Too naughty in their eyes and the airline will be told to deny you boarding.

Safest would be to change to a flight from New York to Amsterdam that's either direct, or changes in another Schengen country. You do still risk intra-EU information sharing on previous entry denials, but assuming you have a valid and non-infringing reason to be in Amsterdam, you should be fine to enter that way